# Why does image keep replicating when being width set to 100% and how to fix this?

Tags: css, background-image

So I am creating a website for practice and I want an image to span across the website and be 400px high. But it turns out that the image is replicating it self into the two of the same images in order to expand across the webpage the height is fine.
1) Why is the happening.
2)How do I fix this below you will find my code.

```
.image {
background-image:url("sauce.png");
height: 400px;
width: 100%;
position: center;}

<div class="image"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension and position properties of the container are not related to background image. Try the following instead:

```
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Also, if you want the background-image to fill the entire area, you can use
`background-size: cover;` which will crop and fill the container maintaining the aspect ratio, or `background-size: contain;` which will squeeze the entire image in the container, distorting the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the CSS [background-repeat](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp) property which by default is set to `repeat`.

In your CSS for `.image`, add the following line: `background-repeat: no-repeat;`.

Comment: I tried that and it worked, but know the problem is that the image is aligned to the left and not center I tried vertical-align: middle; and position: center;. Is there a way where I can get the image center. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.